# How to identify what type of body is yours

Tags: diet, bodybuilding

I agree that different exercise suits for different body types. Different diet ,proteins etc. are good for one body type and may not be good for the other. But how can one identify their build or type of body.

According to me the first step in Body building or having a healthy body is identifying your body type. After identifying one's body only can one have the desired progress in the stipulated or expected time(as one can clearly follow his/her given exercises ) and then maintain a strict diet for his/her particular body.(could be fat, lean, athletic etc.).

Also please clarify how and based on what is the body classified.

Comment: Most weightlifting folk don't believe in bodytypes anymore for two reasons. First, they have been used as a silly excuse for not eating enough/too much way too often. Second, they can only give a very rough guideline which isn't of much use. The much more reasonable, but also slower and work-intensive way is to start somewhere, anywhere, really. And from there on adjust accordingly. More leg training if your arms are too big, more food if you don't gain weight etc.

Comment: Proteins are better for one "body type" than another? After 30 years in exercise science and 40 in athletics, I have heard something new. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop. Drop this idea that you 'have a body type' and need to work a certain way based on this predisposed attribute.

Picture the ideal body, the one you wish you had. This is where the variation is; some people will picture an Arnold, some a LeBron, some a Phelps, others a Froning. When you choose your workouts, you will want to adjust them based on *this* body type, your goal. Obviously your potential is limited to some degree by your height, but in terms of muscle size and appearance you can seek to achieve whatever you view as best.

This does not mean it will be equally easy to fit the mold of every body type. A skinny 6 footer will have a much easier time looking like Phelps than Arnold, because his body is currently closer to that point. This **does not** mean that he can't eventually achieve a very muscular body, just that the distance to this point is greater. Don't limit yourself by classifying your body to be of a certain type.

Comment: ok then suppose a skinny 6 footer targets Arnold kind body(muscles) then does that mean that that skinny will   start directly with lifting 40 kg weights directly or he will lift the weights according to his body limits and then gradually increase(not to be mean or something but you yourself have specified skinny which I guess is based on some criteria)

Comment: @user285oo6 The program you do will be limited by your strength, but within these limitations the program can be adjusted for your specific goal. When you first start lifting, the strategy is going to be pretty similar regardless of what you're shooting for.